# What is Alamofire's .responseString method for?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I know the name is pretty self explanatory that the method returns a string but I'd like to learn how is it helpful to return a string from a networking response?  I was under the impression that network responses always came in either XML format or JSON format.  Can we create a hypothetical example?  If we receive XML from a network call, can you use the responseString method?  And if so, how is it helpful? (i.e debugging purposes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a popular 3rd library it should provide the developers with  all the ways that they want to handle their responses , as it's a responseString it doesn't mean that the Api sends plain string like "anyText" it can be json/xmlString that will be serialized when received

Comment: Oh!  So it would be similar to a data object you receive from a SessionDataTask in which its up to the developer to decide what they'd like to do with the data object? @Sh_Khan

Comment: yes , it also depends on the deal between the developer and the web guy